# How to make the discord bot queue local mp3?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py, replit

I'm new to python, so I wonder if there's a way to do so.

Here's my play mp3 command:

```
@bot.command()
async def play_song1(ctx):
  global voice
  channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
  voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

  if voice and voice.is_connected():
    await voice.move_to(channel)
  else:
    voice = await channel.connect()
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('./mp3/song1.mp3'))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.1
    await ctx.send ('playing')
    while voice.is_playing():
      await asyncio.sleep(.1)  
    await voice.disconnect()
```

I made 2 more same commands but for `song2` and `song3`, and now I want to queue the mp3 when someone calls them.

Comment: @Lemon.py `from discord.utils import get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seen as if you're not using cogs, you could try something like this:

```
guild_queues = {}  # Multi-server support as a dict, just use a list for one server

# EDIT: Map song names in a dict
play_messages = {
    "song1": "Now playing something cool!",
    "song2": "And something even cooler just started playing!",
    "song3": "THE COOLEST!"
}


async def handle_queue(ctx, song):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if voice and channel and voice.channel != channel:
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    elif not voice and channel:
        voice = await channel.connect()
    if not voice.is_playing():
        audio = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"./{song}.mp3")
        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(audio)
        source.volume = 0.1
        voice.play(audio)
        await ctx.send(play_messages[song])
        while voice.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(.1)
        if len(guild_queues[ctx.guild.id]) > 0:
            next_song = guild_queues[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)
            await handle_queue(ctx, next_song)
        else:
            await voice.disconnect()


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, song):  # I'd recommend adding the filenames as an arg, but it's up to you
    # Feel free to add a check if the filename exists
    try:
        # Get the current guild's queue
        queue = guild_queues[ctx.guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        # Create a queue if it doesn't already exist
        guild_queues[ctx.guild.id] = []
        queue = guild_queues[ctx.guild.id]

    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    queue.append(song)
    # The one song would be the one currently playing
    if voice and len(queue) > 0:
        await ctx.send("Added to queue!")
    else:
        current_song = queue.pop(0)
        await handle_queue(ctx, current_song)
```

---

### References:

- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Client.voice_clients`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.voice_clients)
- [`Context.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild)
- [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel)
- [`VoiceClient.move_to()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.move_to)
- [`VoiceClient.is_playing()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.is_playing)
- [`VoiceClient.play()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.play)
- [`discord.FFmpegPCMAudio()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.FFmpegPCMAudio)
- [`discord.PCMVolumeTransformer()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PCMVolumeTransformer)
- [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)

Comment: @jaos1 Sorry, I only just saw your edit! I've just edited my answer - you're able to map some values to song names in a dict

Comment: Now it does add the song to the queue, but it keeps looping the first song, why?

Comment: @jaos1 Sorry about that, fixed up my answer!

Comment: @jaos1 The disconnect line was under-indented, give it another go now